# Is there a life cycle policy that i can setup to move the files in s3 bucket to a folder on a daily basis

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a requirement to roll all the files that are in S3 every day to a folder with in s3 e.g. folder name is the date. Can I setup any lifecycle managment for this purpose.I am looking for some out of box solution/configuration instead of aws command line.

Answer (score 3):

Lifecycle policies never change paths.  They only change storage classes and/or purge objects.

S3 is an object store, not a filesystem.  A better design would probably be to store the objects in the correct place, initially, rather than trying to move them.  Moving 1000 objects requires 2000 or 3000 API requests -- copy, verify, delete.  There is no atomic "move" or "rename" operation, and there are no folder-level or wildcard operations.  Anything that appears to do that -- including the S3 console -- is emulating it with copy [+ verify] + delete requests for the individual objects.

Comment: Thank you Michael. That really helps.  Now, I will change my client code to create a date folder  while writing file into S3 bucket.

Comment: @myPavi note also that there is actually no need to "create" the folder, because it is not a container.  Simply create the objects with the desired path prefix, e.g. `things/2017-11-18/item1.txt`.  Neither `things/` nor `things/2017-11-18/` needs to actually exist in order to create that `item1.txt` object "inside" them, yet the console will still display folders there if any objects with those prefixes exist.

Comment: Got it Thank you. I was able to setup with prefix in the key path and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3's replication policy to copy the object from a source to destination S3 bucket. Along with it you can configure a life cycle policy to delete the objects in source bucket after a certain duration

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).